# Size of an “average” ϵ-net on the unit sphere

Tags: pr.probability, lower-bounds, expectation

This is a question I [originally asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135039/size-of-an-average-epsilon-net-on-the-unit-sphere) on math.stackexchange, but didn't receive a satisfying answer.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider constructing a set $S_\epsilon\subseteq S^{d-1}$ of points on the sphere $\{x\in\mathbb R^d \mid \left\|x\right\|_2=1\}$, such that
$$
\mathbb E\left[\min_{y\in S_\epsilon}\left\|x-y\right\|_2^2\right]\le \epsilon,
$$

where $x$ is a random point on the sphere and the expectation is with respect to the choice of $x$.

> **How big must $S_\epsilon$ be?**

---

I'm looking for a lower bound, although an upper bound may be interesting as well.

---

The motivation for this problem comes from an attempt to prove a lower bound on the number of bits that are needed to send a real-valued vector $x\in\mathbb R^d$ such that the receiver can estimate $x$ to within an ($\ell_2$ squared) error of $\epsilon\left\|x\right\|_2^2$. The formulation requires a few extra steps (including Yao's Minimax principle), but this is the component I'm missing.

Comment: Let $A(d,r)$ be the area on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ within Euclidean distance $r$ from the north pole. Then one lower bound is $2A(d,\sqrt{2})/A(d,\sqrt{\epsilon})$. There are formulas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Hyperspherical_cap and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238156/what-is-the-surface-area-of-a-cap-on-a-hypersphere